Is there a name for the abelian part of a finitely generated Abelian-by-$\mathbb Z^n$ group?
Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated Abelian-by-$\mathbb Z^n$ group, i.e. it admits a short exact sequence $1 \to A \to G \to \mathbb{Z}^n \to 1$ where $A$ is (potentially infinitely generated) abelian. In the case when $n = 1$, then there is a group isomorphism from $A$  to a finitely generated module over the ring of integer Laurent polynomials.
I was wondering if there is a nice description for $A$ in the case when $n>2$. (Another slightly related question: Is there an example when $A$ is not of the form of a finitely generated module over the ring of integer Laurent polynomials?)
Thank you for reading. Any insight will be really appreciated.

It would be nice if you made your soft question a little bit harder. There are two reasonable versions of this: require commutant subgroup to be finitely generated over Z[Gab], or to be finitely generated over Z[F], where F is some arbitrary free quotient with abelian kernel. Which one are you interested in, and why?
